# Sas in Unix: backspace and delete keys are not working

Tags: unix, sas

I have invoked sas in "window environment" through Unix. But I could not use the backspace and delete keys in the program editor. I went into Tools> Options > Keys to try to set the DMKEYS but I do not know how to setup the backspace and delete key there.

My sas is 9.1

Hope you can help me.
Leo

Comment: What do you mean by  - invoked sas in "window environment" through Unix?

Comment: are you referring to X Window software emulator program?

Comment: Hi Neomen, in Unix, I type sas in the command line. Then Sas pop up like the program editor etc.

Comment: This is probably an issue with your terminal setup in your telnet/terminal program (or however you connect).  Backspace key is not always really backspace key; sometimes they are ctrl+h.  You should specify which program or method you're using to connect to Unix.

Comment: Hi Joe, I am using xterm to connect. I can use backspace easily in the command line of Unix. Just that when I invoke Sas, I cant use backspace or delete button like it should. I have to first move the cursor to the character and backspace/delete to delete the character at the cursor. It wont automatically delete and shift left.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off numlock.  That enables delete and backspace within several x emulators, like xMing

Answer (score 0):

Some programs ignore the terminal database, and have the *erase* character hardcoded.  Usually that is a choice between

- ASCII BS (**backspace**, shown as `^H`) and
- ASCII DEL (**delete**, shown as `^?`).

Just because your keyboard has *Backspace* printed on it doesn't mean that is what is sent. Given one, you can use the control key to enter the other using xterm, e.g., type (together) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Backspace</kbd>